# Error de compilación; calificador no válido

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo este código de VBA y me sale error de compilación y resalta Nombre en las lineas finales, por  favor me podrían colaborar.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()  
Dim NOMBRE As String  
Dim APELLIDO As String  
Dim ID As Long  

'Saludo  
NOMBRE = InputBox("Ingrese su nombre")  
APELLIDO = InputBox("Ingrese su apellido")  

MsgBox "Hola:" & " " & NOMBRE & " " & APELLIDO & vbNewLine & "Su fecha de ingreso es:" & " " & Date & vbNewLine & "Su hora de ingreso es:" & " " & Time  


' Costruir base de datos  
    With Registro
    ID = Sheets("Registro").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1up).Row + 1
    End With

Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select  
ActiveCell.Value = ID  
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Date  
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Time  
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = NOMBRE.Text 'aquí resalta el error en NOMBRE  
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = APELLIDO.Text  


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te está resaltando esta línea

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = NOMBRE.Text 'aquí resalta el error en NOMBRE
```

Porque estás intentando recuperar el valor que tiene una variable, poniendo la propiedad ".Text", que no es válida.

Para que no te dé el error, tendrías que cambiar la línea por la siguiente:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = NOMBRE
```

Te va a pasar lo mismo en la línea de abajo, en la del apellido.

Las variables no tienen propiedad .Text, para acceder al valor que tienen, únicamente hay que poner el nombre de la variable.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, ya realicé los cambios y ahora me aparece error de desbordamiento, sabes por qué ocurre?

Comment: Dory, podrías poner un pantallazo o el texto del error que te da, para comprobar dónde se está produciendo el desbordamiento?

Comment: El error de desbordamiento suele ser porque estás intentando meter en una variable algo que no cabe. Por ejemplo, un número mayor a 255 en una variable de tipo Byte. Para ver la capacidad de cada tipo de variable, mira https://www.excel-avanzado.com/699/tipos-datos-vba.html